# How to return a private array in a public get method in C++?

Tags: c++, class, getter-setter, encapsulation, return-type

I am trying to make a public member get function that will return the private variable emp. But I am getting an error in my get function that says

> "return value type does not match the function type"

I know that in C++ a return type cannot be an array, rather it must be a pointer to an array. But I am just returning the name of the array which should be the address of the first element.

```
    class DB {

private:
    static const int SIZE = 13;
    Employee* emp[SIZE];

public:
    DB();
    void print(Employee*[], const int);
    Employee* get_emp_arr();
    const int get_emp_arr_size();
}

Employee* DB::get_emp_arr(){
        return this->emp;
    }
```

I have come up with a solution to my error message, but I would like an explanation. Simply by changing the return type to "Employee**", "this->emp" is accepted as a return type.

Comment: Maybe you mean `Employee emp[SIZE];`

Comment: In addition to @Damien's comment:  `const Employee* get_emp_arr();` does not match the implementation which returns a non-`const` `Employee*`

Comment: As the error states, "return value `Employee*` does not match the function type `const Employee* ...`"

Comment: My mistake, the const Employee* was a typo. I removed it but my question is the same.

Comment: With your new edited code, you are returning an object of type `Employee*[13]`, but you are stating the return type as `Employee*`.  Do you see that "an array of 13 pointers to Employee" is not "a pointer to Employee"?

Comment: @LoganGauchat So, did you consider Damien's first comment?

Comment: The array needs to be an array of Employee pointers @damien

Comment: In this case, you have to return `Employee**`

Comment: "_The array needs to be an array of Employee pointers_" - In that case you also need to allocate memory for those 13 `Employee`s.

Comment: @Damien what exactly is the reason? Using ** indicates that the pointer is to a pointer?

Comment: Exactly. It is what you have here. The first pointer is the adress of the array (more or less), and the second one corresponds to the type of the object in the array.

Comment: `return this->emp;` is the same as `return &this->emp[0];` - the location of the array's first element. Since the first element, `emp[0]`, is an `Employee*`, `&emp[0]` is an `Employee**`.

Comment: I don't even think you should return an `Employee*`. It's common to add overloads for `const Employee& operator[](size_t idx) const;` and `Employee& operator[](size_t idx);` to return a reference to the element at the index you want. Well, you could have a `Employee* data() { return emp; }` and `const Employee* data() const { return emp; }` too, like `vector`s have. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/erEbdcnEh)

Comment: @Ted: `data`'s return type would be a double-pointer, just like `get_emp_arr()` in the question (really, this whole class should be replaced by `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>>`, whose `data()` function would also be a double pointer, namely `std::unique_ptr<Employee> *`).  You can implicitly deference the extra pointer in `operator[]` as long as no one tries to do pointer arithmetic on `&db[i]`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suggested that OP replaced `Employee* emp[SIZE];` with `Employee emp[SIZE];` (or rather, Damien did and I concurred) so it'd just be an `Employee*` that's returned (and I included that in the example to show how it could look) - but yes, replacing the fixed size array with a `std::vector` of some sort would probably be preferable unless the `DB` is supposed to hold exactly 13 employees at all times (which seems impractical and unusual).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your definition of the "emp" array.

```
Employee* emp[SIZE];
```

This is supposed to be an array of employees, but actually it's an array of **pointers** to employees. To understand why the return type `Employee**` works, you have to understand how arrays work in C++. Different to other languages where arrays store their length or similar, in C++ an array is just several objects of the same type that are adjacent in memory. This means that an arrays is nothing different than a pointer to the place in memory where the first item is stored. `myArray[0].smth()` is equivalent to `myArray->smth()`, and `myArray[1].smth()` is equivalent to `(myArray+1)->smth()`. To fix your problem you have two options:

1. Change the return type to `Employee**` or
2. Change the variables type to `Employee[]`